# My odoo installed on local Ubuntu server keeps on crashing after power outage

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

This is the message I get after trying to start Odoo service

```
 odoo-server.service - Odoo Open Source
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/odoo-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-06-17 14:33:57 EAT; 20s ago
  Process: 4389 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /opt/odoo/smoothel_odoo/odoo-bin --config=/home/erpsvr/.odoorc (code=exited, status=216/GROUP)
 Main PID: 4389 (code=exited, status=216/GROUP)
```

Comment: Try to run `/usr/bin/python3 /opt/odoo/smoothel_odoo/odoo-bin --config=/home/erpsvr/.odoorc` and see if any error is logged.

Comment: Thanks Kenly. Got a solution that the odoo service was being run on terminal and the odoo service file was misconfigured

Comment: I'm glad it helped.